# C++ combine vector in vector into one vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have to combine vectors in one vector then push back to another vector, if I use `.insert`, the vectors will be still separate.

Below is my code:

```
vector<vector<char>> first_all;
vector<vector<char>> first_of_first;
for(vector<char>::iterator f_all_it = first.begin(); f_all_it != first.end(); f_all_it++) {
    if(*f_all_it != ',') {
        vector<char> tmp_first;
        vector<char> tmp_first_all;
        tmp_first = this->dic.find(*f_all_it)->second;
        vector<char> tmp_fof;
        for(vector<char>::iterator fof_it = tmp_first.begin(); fof_it != tmp_first.end(); fof_it++) {
            vector<char> v_in_fof = this->dic.find(*fof_it)->second;
            for(vector<char>::iterator inner_it = v_in_fof.begin(); inner_it != v_in_fof.end(); inner_it++) {
                tmp_fof.push_back(*inner_it);
            }
        }
        first_of_first.push_back(tmp_fof);
        tmp_first_all = this->total.find(*f_all_it)->second;
        first_all.push_back(tmp_first_all);
    }
}
```

How can I make my vectors in vector be combined?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking - do you mean that you need to concatenate one vector onto another, and that onto a third?

Comment: @Invictus Suppose there are two vectors in my `tmp_fof`, and I have to concatenate them. Then, push them into my `first_of_first`.

Comment: Then why is your result of type `vector<vector<char>>` and not `vector<char>`? Can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: @interjay I still have to use type of `vector<vector<char>>`, so I have to concatenate the `tmp_first`. I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know that i understood you correctly or not. However, you can easily use insert function in vectors Here is simply example:

```
std::vector<int> X;   
std::vector<int> Y;
std::vector<int> XandY;   // result vector.

XandY.reserve( X.size() + Y.size() ); // allocate memory for result vector 
XandY.insert( XandY.end(), X.begin(), X.end() );  // make your insert operation..
XandY.insert( XandY.end(), Y.begin(), Y.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need those intermediate vectors. As far as I can understand you have three vectors and you want to copy the content of the first two to the last one. This can be simply achieve with `std::copy`.

```
vector<vector<char>> v1 = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e'}};
vector<vector<char>> v2 = {{'e', 'f', 'g'}};
vector<vector<char>> v3 = {{'h', 'i'}};

std::copy(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2), std::back_inserter(v1));
std::copy(std::begin(v3), std::end(v3), std::back_inserter(v1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are getting at - you want something like this:

```
vector<vector<char>> tmp_fof;
vector<char> first_of_first;

first_of_first.insert(first_of_first.end(), tmp_fof.at(1).begin(), tmp_fof.at(1).end())
first_of_first.insert(first_of_first.end(), tmp_fof.at(1).begin(), tmp_fof.at(1).end())
```